# Create a postgresql deployment using the postgresql-persistent template in OpenShift

Tags: postgresql, openshift, openshift-origin

I created an OpenShift instance on my computer using the `oc cluster up` command.

Then I want to create a postgresql application deployment using a template. 
If I do it through the OpenShift UI it works well.

but if I do it using this command :

```
oc new-app --template=postgresql-persistent --param=NAMESPACE=airsonic-demo --param=DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME=postgresql --param=POSTGRESQL_USER=airsonic --param=POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=**** --param=POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=airsonic --param=VOLUME_CAPACITY=30Mi --param=POSTGRESQL_VERSION=9.5
```

it does not work because the resulting deployment config has no image and I got the following message when I want to deploy this application.

> Reason: cannot trigger a deployment for "postgresql" because it
>   contains unresolved images

Indeed, here is a snippet of the deployment config descriptor. The *image* entry is empty.

```
spec:
  containers:
    - env:
        - name: POSTGRESQL_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: database-user
              name: postgresql
        - name: POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: database-password
              name: postgresql
        - name: POSTGRESQL_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: database-name
              name: postgresql
      image: ' '
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the option ``--param=NAMESPACE=airsonic-demo``. What does it do without that? What does it do if you supply no parameters and you let it use generated values? What version of ``oc`` are you using?

Comment: If I omit the `--param=NAMESPACE=airsonic-demo` argument it works perfectly. Wonderfull. Thanks a lot.